# Difference between Libraries & lib folders ? How do we add jar files to lib folder?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

When i created the dynamic web project, i will have 2 folders with name Libraries and lib. So during the project i added .jar files as follows

```
Build Path --> Configure Build Path--> Libraries (tab) --> Add external JAR's -- > OK
```

When i do this, it will add files to Libraries, However i would like to add .jar files to lib folder.

[image]

I tried copying all .jar files from Libraries to lib, but it says

[image]

Copied .jar files directly to lib folder in directory structure, but i doesn't display in eclipse.

[image]

I would appreciate your suggestions and inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy jars into `WEB-INF/lib` directory by copying files themselves (not from Libraries in eclipse view) and hit refresh from eclipse, they will appear in the `Web App Libraries`

P.S: It is almost always better to use a build tool like maven/ant to manage dependencies

Comment: Can u please tell me the difference between lib and libraries ?

Comment: When you create a war/ear file, jars in Library section will not be included where as the ones in lib will packaged in to the war/ear. If you dont need a jar file to be packaged in the war, maybe because app server already provides or you only need it during compilation.... you can use that part.

Comment: so during run time JVM will look for jar files in lib folder instead of Libraries. where as libraries folder is only for compilation :)

Comment: when you create a package and deploy it, yes. When you run in inside eclipse it may already be including paths to Library jars as well. ideally using a build tool like maven would make job easier

Answer (score 0):

- Open the lib folder in the file browser and paste all the copied
  jars.
- Refresh the lib folder in the