# how to add .jar file into android dependencies folder

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have a problem, I need to add a `.jar` file into android dependencies folder in eclipse. I have looked for similar stack posts but none of them worked for me.

I have tried pasting the jar file into the libs folder but it gives an error

> cannot copy the clipboard content into the selected items"

I have to deliver my work by tomorrow. Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: tried the above link already.. does'nt works

Answer (score 1):

Add it to the classpath, which is specified by the "Java Build Path" menu in the project properties.

More info here: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-properties-build-path.htm

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the ADT plugin for Eclipse, you must add it to your classpath. Simply right-click on your project, choose 'Properties', go to the 'Java Build Path' tab, and, in the 'Libraries' tab, click "Add External JARs" and import your JAR. This will auto-import the file and allow you to use it in your projects.

Your problem may be similar to this one: [Difference between Libraries & lib folders ? How do we add jar files to lib folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10399617/difference-between-libraries-lib-folders-how-do-we-add-jar-files-to-lib-fold?rq=1)